# Saboteur - ladder card

Tags: saboteur-2

When playing Saboteur card game for 2, where can you put the ladder card? Can you e.g. put it next to a brown card, once it has been turned and there is no gold on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The can never be placed next to a goal card even if there is no gold on the card.

[Rules](http://tesera.ru/images/items/98031/Saboteur_expansion_rules.pdf)

> Path with a Ladder (4 in game)
>   The path on this card is always
>   connected to the Start Card and to
>   all other cards with a ladder.
>   It always has to touch a path card
>   and cannot be placed next to a goal
>   card